# Can't cast Holoeverywhere application to getapplicationcontext

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

I have extended the application class to add some preference to my app, i started to implement holoeverywhere, and now i'm getting this error:

```
03-28 10:39:10.020: E/AndroidRuntime(12511): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.holoeverywhere.app.Application cannot be cast to com.myapp.Globals
```

in this line:

```
Globals global = (Globals) getApplicationContext();
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what is your Globals class ?

Comment: but, its not an activity, do i have to declare it in the manifest? how?
Globals is:
`public class Globals extends Application`

Comment: @Edgar, Since it's an `Application`, you have to declare it as well. `<application android:name="your.package.name.Globals">`. Also make sure you are extending `org.holoeverywhere.app.Application` and not `android.app.Application`

Comment: i am extending holoeverywhere application, but if i use `<application android:name="your.package.name.Globals">` i got an error, saying that i need to use org.holoeverywhere.app.Application

Comment: Im sorry, you were right, it worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.holoeverywhere.app.Application;

public class Globals extends Application {
  ..
}

<application android:name="com.package.Globals"
  ..
/>

Globals application = (Globals) getApplication();
```